# Deploying selenium scraper on Linux server

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The above code do not work on linux machine,not on server, neither Docker. I have troubles with clicking on btns, as locally everything works perfectly. Is there any option to fix that or atleast get to know what is happening in google chrome inside linux server?

```
import time
import json
import uvicorn

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from fastapi import FastAPI,status,HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse



app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/ozon_req",status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_ozon(user_prompt:int):
    response_json = []
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.165 Safari/537.36")
        options.add_argument("accept=*/*")
        s = Service(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=options)

        driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
            'source': '''
                delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
                delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
                delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
        '''
        })

 driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(f"https://www.ozon.ru/product/{user_prompt}")
        time.sleep(10)
        btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,f'pl6').click()
        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'lxml')
        test = soup.find(class_='p5l')
        print(test.text)
        brand = soup.find_all(class_='j5s')
        print(brand[1].text)
        main_div = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'pl6')
        for i in range(1,len(main_div)+1):
            btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,f'pl6').click()
            time.sleep(10)
            page_source = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"lxml")
            test = soup.find(class_='p5l')
            print(test.text)
            sku = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/span').text
            brand = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/dl[2]/dd/a').text
            price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="layoutPage"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/span[1]/span').text
            seller = soup.find(class_='jp2').text
            dictionary = {
                "data":[
                { 'sku':sku.text,
                'brand': brand.text,
                'seller': seller.text,
                'price': price.text}]
                }
            response_json.append(dictionary)
            print(dictionary)
            time.sleep(5)

        return response_json

    except Exception as ex:
        with open("ozon.json","a",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            error_dict = {
                "message": "similar products not found"
            }
            file.write(json.dumps(error_dict))
        print(ex)

        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail="Similar products not found")


if name == "main":
    uvicorn.run(
    "ozon_artgor:app",
    port=8000,
    host='0.0.0.0',
    reload=True
    );
```

I assume that problem in cloudflare, as this website use cloudlflare to prevent parcing, also driver.find_element(By.XPATH) do not work in any way on linux.

Comment: using `time.sleep` isn't a good practice, try using `WebDriverWait` function to wait for the load of the element and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, "do not work" is far from a useful problem description.